# React router : blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is how the router I defined :

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import PersonsList from './PersonsList';
import Error from './Error'
import Person from './Person'

const Router = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/persons" strict={false} component={PersonsList}/>
            <Route path="/persons/:id" component={Person}/>
            <Route component={Error}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Router;
```

The first route works perfectly.

The problem is that in the `PersonsList`, when I try to reach the `/persons/:id` route, I get a blank page.

Here is the code I use for redirection in the PersonsList component :

```
static propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object
};

handleRedirection = (aPerson) => {
    this.props.history.push(`/persons/${aPerson.id}`);
}

...

{this.state.persons.map(aPerson => (
    <React.Fragment key={aPerson.id}>
        <div className="row" onClick={this.handleRedirection.bind(this,aPerson)}>
```

Here is the `Person` component :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class Person extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        match: PropTypes.object 
    };

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log('the selected person : ' + this.props.match.params.id);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>A person</div>
        )
    }
}


export default withRouter(Person);
```

I can see the `console.log` output but no rendering of the `<div>A person</div>`.

**Question** 
Why the second route returns a blank content knowing its component's constructor is called? Why the rendering is not processed ?

Comment: I can't see what's wrong with your code, but [my simple example works](https://codesandbox.io/s/m2po4p9x). Maybe you could look at that and see what differs?

Comment: My problem appear when I try to navigate from `PersonsList` to `Person`. The first loading works perfectly.

Comment: It does `this.props.history.push('/persons/testing');` in my example. Compare that to your code and see if you see something different.

Comment: Thank you. As stated : the targeted component's constructor is called. The only problem I have is the rendering. I don't know why nothing shows.

Answer (score 0):

i try this.props.history.push('/home'); code part but not correct running.

you can see my component codes in the below.
my full component code :

```
class Full extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <Header/>
                <div className="app-body">
                    <Sidebar {...this.props}/>
                    <main className="main">
                        <Breadcrumb/>
                        <Container fluid>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path="/dashboard" name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
                                <Route path="/applications" name="Applications" component={Applications}/>
                                <Route path="/roles" name="Roles" component={Roles}/>
                                <Route path="/poc" name="poc" component={Poc}/>
                                <Redirect from="/home" to="/dashboard"/>
                            </Switch>
                        </Container>
                    </main>
                    <Aside/>
                </div>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Dashboard component code :

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
        <div>test</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

History Code:

```
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';
export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```